# htaccess first page masking multiple variables

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

how can first category page (page/1) masking on htaccess. i need one line writing this code?

```
RewriteRule ^animal$ categorie.php?cID=1&page=1 [L]
RewriteRule ^animal/page/([0-9]+)$ categorie.php?cID=1&page=1$ [L]
```

my another category like this:

```
www.domain.com/women  = domain.com?catID=2&page=1
www.domain.com/women/page/2 = domain.com?catID=2&page=2
```

i have **11 categories**

sorry for english.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, if you're going to translate a category *name* (animal, women,...) into an ID *number*, that's going to have to be done case by case. Think about passing the category *name* (`catName=$1`) instead of a number `cId=nnn`. Then you would set the cId *inside* your PHP code.

If no page is given, you would need a separate RewriteRule to handle a default of page 1.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  ^([^/]+)/?$  /category.php?catName=$1&page=1 [QSA]
RewriteRule  ^([^/]+)/page/([0-9]+)/?$  /category.php?catName=$1&page=$2  [QSA]
```

is one way to do it.

Now, in /category.php, you have `$_GET['catName']` that you can look up the $catID for, and `$_GET['page']` should be set. To be safe, check that they are set with isset(), and perhaps check for valid values.

Comment: This is not what I want. this is for category, have a under category some news pages. this time all mixing. 

example: `RewriteRule ^animal/([a-z0-9-]+)$ news.php?url=$1&cID=1 [L]`

Answer (score 0):

i solved like this.

```
RewriteRule ^(animal|women|live|football)$ /categorie.php?cat=$1&page=1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(animal|women|live|football)/page/([0-9]+)$ /categorie.php?cat=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

thanks

Comment: Which is basically what I suggested, except that you only do it for specific category names, not any name.

Comment: yes my categories all stable. for this i must speedy query. this only category side have news, galery, tags for this i must split and quick send rewrite.